# I'd like to go on a moose safari in Sweden. What are my options?

Tags: sweden, safari, nature-and-wildlife

I've been in Sweden for some time now, but never had a chance to go on a moose safari so far. To clear up any confusion, this is the kind of trip where you walk around through the forest, enjoy the fresh air and shoot moose *with your camera*.

Here's one specimen, in all its glory[image]

Some requirements and notes:

- I'm currently residing in Småland, so a close location would be nice. Failing that, anything south of Stockholm is an option.
- I'd prefer a place easily accessible by bus or other public transport (I don't currently own a car, and hiring is kind of expensive in Sweden). Bonus points if the journey starts from a nearby town or a city.
- Price is not very important, as long as it's good value
- Sharing personal experiences will be highly appreciated
- I can hunt down additional information about a location myself, as long as I'm pointed in the right direction.

Comment: In Sweden I believe the thing in the picture is called an Elk.

Comment: Actually neither. It's "Älg". Although if you wanted to ask in english "moose" is going to have a higher success rate.

Answer (score 10):

There is a "älgsafari" [just outside Markaryd in Småland](http://www.smalandet.se/), went there with my kids this summer and they loved it. It's a drive-through safari, I don't think you're allowed on foot.

Comment: That's a great place to visit if you like to see mooses up close. https://www.tripadvisor.se/Attraction_Review-g1588184-d3545858-Reviews-Smalandet_Markaryds_Algsafari-Markaryd_Kronoberg_County.html

Answer (score 6):

[Here's a BBC story about an elk sighting near Gothenburg](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-14842999), a major city in southern Sweden. It's a bit dramatic, but illustrates a point about availability.

Comment: Yeah, elk sighting are not uncommon, but I'm looking for an organized activity, like in an elk farm, so that I have a good chance of spotting at least one. Besides, the Swedish countryside is vast, and one needs to know *where* to look for them -- which brings us back to square one.

Answer (score 2):

For Moose Safaris with guaranteed wild sightings just 2 hours from Stockholm, check out [Wild Sweden](http://www.wildsweden.com).

** disclosure - affiliated with company.

Comment: Hi Marcus, welcome to Travel.SE.  While a relevant answer, we do ask that you indicate when you have an affiliate or are recommending your own site, in this case. Thanks for the answer though, I'm just editing it for clarity.